# I need to compare data from two tables and show them all in the new table

Tags: mysql

I need to compare data from two table (tbl1 and tbl2) and show them all in the new table (tbl_new).

tbl01

```
------------------------------
price     mat_group     major
------------------------------
100       a001          a
200       a002          a
450       a003          a
520       b001          b
250       b002          b
170       c001          c
80        c002          c
```

tbl02

```
------------------------------
price     mat_group     major
------------------------------
150       a001          a
180       a002          a
320       a003          a
220       b001          b
350       b002          b
520       c003          c
```

tbl_new

```
---------------------------------------------
t1.price     t2.price     mat_group     major
---------------------------------------------
100          150          a001          a
200          180          a002          a
450          320          a003          a
520          220          b001          b
250          350          b002          b
170                       c001          c     
80                        c002          c  
             520          c003          c
```

Please give me some MySQL syntax?

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?  This looks like homwork.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a combination of **`LEFT JOIN`**. First join first table with a sub-query of unique `mat_group` values and then join it with the second table.

**Query**

```
select 
  `t`.`price_1`, 
  `t`.`price_2`, 
  coalesce(`t`.`mat_group_1`, `t`.`mat_group_2`) as `mat_group`, 
  coalesce(`t`.`major_1`, `t`.`major_2`) as `major`
from(
  select 
    `t1`.`price` as `price_1`, 
    `t1`.`mat_group` as `mat_group_1`, 
    `t1`.`major` as `major_1`,
    `t2`.`price` as `price_2`, 
    `t2`.`mat_group` as `mat_group_2`, 
    `t2`.`major` as `major_2` 
  from(
    select `mat_group` from `tbl01`
    union
    select `mat_group` from `tbl02`
  ) as `mg` 
  left join `tbl01` as `t1`
  on `t1`.`mat_group` = `mg`.`mat_group` 
  left join `tbl02` as `t2`
  on `t2`.`mat_group` = `mg`.`mat_group`
) as `t`;
```

**[Find a fiddle demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a27a8a/2)**

Comment: your answer resolve my problem. thank you very much.

Comment: @ESpaDA Please mark it as answer if this solved your problem